# What is the use of observer property didSet and willSet in Swift language?

Tags: swift, properties

I am new to swift language .The swift offers new object oriented feature property observer "willSet" and "didSet".How it is  different from common objective C property .

Comment: Did you read "Property Observers" section [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)?

Comment: But didn't figure out. I need a good example

Comment: See this simple example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/536/variables-properties/5220/property-observers#t=201609021224585721363

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main usage is to capture and escalate the old and new values of the variable. `willSet` captures the `newValue` to which the property, variable, is about to be set and `didSet` captures the oldValue.

They're extremely handy for setup and teardowns... e.g.

```
var fileHandle: FileHandle {
    willSet{
        otherClass.disableAccessTo(handle: newValue)
    }
    didSet{
        otherClass.enableAccessTo(handle: self.fileHandle)
        yetAnotherClass.archiveFile(handle: oldValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I use property observers and more specific `didSet`for various things.

One example could be in a `UIViewController` where you have a `UITableView` and an array that holds the elements you'd like populate your table view from:

```
var persons: [Person]? = nil
```

now, every time you change something in your `persons` array, you'd like the table view to reload.

```
var persons: [Person]? = nil {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Another example could be `@IBOutlets`, if you'd like to set text color, font, background color and so on. Normally you'd do this in `viewDidLoad()` or some place like that, but now you can to that in `didSet` too, like so:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            headerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
            headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("logIn", comment: "")
        }
    }
```

Now, when your `headerLabel` is initialized, these properties are set.

Hope that gives you an idea about how to use property observers :)